# Moveable ArcGIS Identify Popup Window (Dojo)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, dojo

I'm trying to get a popup window that identifies a location to be moveable. My code is similar to the API example:

```
var popupOptions = {
    fillSymbol: new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0]), 2),
                new dojo.Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25]))
}

var popup = new esri.dijit.Popup(popupOptions, dojo.create("div"));

map = new esri.Map("map", {
    infoWindow:popup,
    extent: initExtent
});
```

I can't seem to find anywhere that will allow me to make that popup infowindow moveable (was thinking of trying to implement dojo.dnd.moveable).

I've tried, unsucessfully:

```
function makeMoveable(node){
    var dnd = new dojo.dnd.Moveable(dojo.byId(node));
}
makeMoveable(popup);
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: If I were you I wouldn't use `dijit`'s made by ESRI. I work a lot with esri JS api and I've found lots of bugs in those. And IMO those modules are not very configurable.

Comment: I previously thought about doing something similar, but making the popup moveable is only part of the problem - the window points to the location it references using one of these images: http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.3/js/esri/dijit/images/popup.png Unless you want to get into a rather sticky problem you will have to live with the popup no longer pointing to the correct location

Answer (score 6):

This blog has an excellent example of how to make the window draggable and hide the arrow using dojo: https://gavinr.com/2015/04/13/arcgis-javascript-draggable-infowindow

Here's the key javascript snippet:

```
require([
    'esri/arcgis/utils',
    'dojo/dnd/Moveable',
    'dojo/query',
    'dojo/on',
    'dojo/dom-class'
], function (
    arcgisUtils,
    Moveable,
    query,
    on,
    domClass
) {
    var webMapItemID = "fe0827dfea2441f5b206b0e2c37b79cd";
    arcgisUtils.createMap(webMapItemID, "map", {}).then(function(response) {
        var map = response.map;
        var handle = query(".title", map.infoWindow.domNode)[0];
        var dnd = new Moveable(map.infoWindow.domNode, {
            handle: handle
        });

        // when the infoWindow is moved, hide the arrow:
        on(dnd, 'FirstMove', function() {
            // hide pointer and outerpointer (used depending on where the pointer is shown)
            var arrowNode =  query(".outerPointer", map.infoWindow.domNode)[0];
            domClass.add(arrowNode, "hidden");

            var arrowNode =  query(".pointer", map.infoWindow.domNode)[0];
            domClass.add(arrowNode, "hidden");
        }.bind(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a div with id identifyDiv to your html code and change you javascript to be

```js
var popup = new esri.dijit.Popup({popupOptions}, "identifyDiv");

map = new esri.Map("map", {
    infoWindow:popup,
    extent: initExtent
});

makeMoveable("identifyDiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to my question, I decided to not make this box moveable and keep the close icon for the users.